# How to set button at bottom

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi. How to set the position of the button bottom and responsive. I set the margin-top for the div button but when the screen is changed to the phone screen the position of the button will be far from the picture. Can you share your opinion on how I can change the position of the button and make it responsive.

css:

```
 html { font-size: 22px; }
body { padding: 1rem; }

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
 
}

.cards {
  max-width: 850px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
}

/* Screen larger than 600px? 2 column */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
}

/* Screen larger than 900px? 3 columns */
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }
}
```

Code:

```
<div class="cards">
                    <div class="card"> <img src="assets/images/csc.png" width="200" height="280" ></div>
                    <div class="card"><img src="assets/images/nist.png" width="350" height="280" ></div>
                    <div class="card" style="height: auto; width: fit-content; "><button class="button1" style="height: 45px; width: 120px;"><b>Take me to <br> NIST website</b></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```